# How to understand the mounted() function in Vue.Js with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to understand how the mounted hook works on Vue.js. If I understand correctly, the mounted function is called when all DOM elements are rendered. So in this scenario, I will have access to the DOM elements with `document.getElementById` or `this.$el.somenthing`.

Is this right?

But why I get the following behavior? Lets say I have the following structure:

```
mounted() {
  this.buildTextTargetWidth();
},
methods: {
  buildTextTargetWidth() {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('typographyTextPreview')); // Empty HTML-Collection. But, curiously, when I open the array in the console, there is the right element.
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('typographyTextPreview')[0]); // Undefined
  },
}
```

So far so good. The result is `undefined`. But for my understanding it should not!

Lets try to add some async stuff to wait 500ms:

```
mounted() {
  this.buildTextTargetWidth();
},
methods: {
  async buildTextTargetWidth() {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
    console.log(document.getElementById('test')); // The element is there
  },
}
```

Now the element is there!

But why I have to wait other 500ms to get the DOM data if the `mounted()` is calling after the DOM is ready? It makes no sense for me.

By the way: The element `typographyTextPreview` which I try to call is embedded inside a `v-for`. Could this be the reason for this behavior? If yes, how could I wait until the v-for is ready?

--EDIT--

I wanted to create this topic as clean and simple as possible. But here I add additional data from the component, for example the entire for loop where the element `typographyTextPreview` is included:

```
<div ref="builderLayer" class="vconf-create-builder column" :class="getColumnLength">
  <div class="vconf-create-builder-layers" :key="layersKey">
      <div v-for="layer of getLayers" class="vconf-create-builder-layer" :key="layer.uid" :style="{ background: 'url(' + getLayerImage(layer) + ') center / contain no-repeat' }">
        <template v-for="tile of layer.data">
          <!-- <VueDragResize :key="tile.uid" v-if="tile.type=='typography'" :parentLimitation="true" :isActive="true" :x="calculatePositionX(tile)" :y="calculatePositionY(tile)" :w="tile.editBoxWidth" :h="tile.editBoxHeight" @resizestop="updateTypoBoxSize($event, layer, tile)" @dragstop="updateTypoBoxPosition($event, layer, tile)">
            <h2 class="typographyTextPreview" :style="{'font-size':calculateFontSize(tile) + 'px', color: tile.fontColor}">{{tile.text ? tile.text : "Please enter an initial text in the settings"}}</h2>
          </VueDragResize> -->
          <div v-if="tile.type=='typography'" class="container" :key="tile.uid">
            <div class="target" :style="buildTextTargetStyle(tile)">
              <h2 id="test" class="typographyTextPreview" :style="{color: tile.fontColor}">{{tile.text ? tile.text : "Please enter an initial text in the settings"}}</h2>
            </div>
            <Moveable
              className="moveable"
              :target="['.target']"
              :keepRatio="true"
              :throttleResize="1"
              :bounds=' {"left":0,"top":0, "right": clientWidth, "bottom": clientHeight}'
              :origin="true"
              :snappable="true"
              :zoom="1"
              :draggable="true"
              :scalable="true"
              :rotatable="true"
              @drag="onDrag($event, tile)"
              @scale="onScale($event, tile)"
              @rotate="onRotate($event, tile)"
            />
          </div>
        </template>          
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you please provide the `typographyTextPreview` element?

Comment: Can you please add few more blocks of code so we can understand better?

Comment: is it a typo that the method you call in "mounted" is called differently than the one you have in "methods"?

Comment: @vladtkachuk no

Comment: Hi guys, I've added more code and corrected the wrong function call. It was just a typo error, yes. In my project the function name is the right one :-)

Comment: What does `getLayers` do? Is it async? If so, then the `typographyTextPreview` won't be in DOM until `getLayers` loads.

Comment: getLayers is a computed property which returns an array from the store. Code: getLayers() {
          return store.formData.structure.layers;
      },

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> A component is considered mounted after:
> All of its synchronous child components have been mounted (does not include async components or components inside  trees).
> Its own DOM tree has been created and inserted into the parent container. Note it only guarantees that the component's DOM tree is in-document if the application's root container is also in-document.

If you need to wait for DOM changes, I suggest you to use the `nextTick` utility, which waits for the DOM to be updated. More details [here](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick)